# Interpolation Function

Tags: python, matlab, pandas, gps

This is probably a very easy question, but all the sources I have found on interpolation in Matlab are trying to correlate two values, all I wanted to benefit from is if I have data which is collected over an 8 hour period, but the time between data points is varying, how do I adjust it such that the time periods are equal and the data remains consistent?

Or to rephrase from the approach I have been trying: I have GPS lat,lon and Unix time for these points; what I want to do is take the lat and lon at time 1 and time 3 and for the case where I don't know time 2, simply fill it with data from time 1 - is there a functional way to do this? (I know in something like Python Pandas you can use fill) but I'm unsure of how to do this in Matlab.

Answer (score 2):

You can look into fitting methods in MATLAB. For example you can look at `polyfit` or `splines`.
Let's look at `polyfit`, the way to use it is:

```
P = polyfit(X,Y,N);
```

Here X is your time data, and Y is your GPS data measured at time values in X. And N is the order of polynomial. When you calculate P then you can use `polyval` function as:

```
Y1 = polyval(P,X1);
```

Here X1 are uniform time samples for example X1=[1 2 3  4 5 6 7 8] in your case and Y1 will be the estimated data at those times, P is what you calculated using `polyfit`.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is use interp1 function. This function will fit in deifferent way the numbers for a new X series.
For example if you have 
x=[1 3 5 6 10 12] 
y=[15 20 17 33 56 89]

This means if you want to fill in for x1=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 ... 12], you will type 
y1=interp1(x,y,x1)

Answer (score 2):

You might try something along the lines of this:

```
 resampledTime = min(unixTime):resampleInterval:max(unixTime);
 resampledLat = interp1(time,lat,resampledTime);
 resampledLon = interp1(time,lon,resampledTime);
```

By default, this returns 1-dimensional linear interpolation. For more info, see `help interp1`

Answer (score 2):

There is a MATLAB function called [interparc.m](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34874-interparc/content/interparc.m) which will benefit you. It fits a cubic spline through the points and divides the resulting line into equal arc-lengths (depending on the number of points entered by the user)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for a "zero-order-hold" interpolation a.k.a "nearest neighbor"

Why don't you try [`interp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html) with method `'nearest'`?